# np.logical_and with three tests

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to update a column in my dataframe based on the testing and results of the values within three columns (3 tests).

Some sample code:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([('?',2.0,1,0,0,0), (None,2.0,1,0,0,0), 
                        (None,2.0,0,0,0,0),(None,2.0,0,1,0,0), 
                        ('?',2.0,0,0,0,0)], columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
df_test.head()
```

When I try the following `df_test['g'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df_test['a'] != 'None', df_test['c'] == 0, df_test['d'] == 0), True, False).astype(int)`
I receive the error `TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType` So I try the following:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([('?',2.0,1,0,0,0), (None,2.0,1,0,0,0), 
                        (None,2.0,0,0,0,0),(None,2.0,0,1,0,0), 
                        ('?',2.0,0,0,0,0)], columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
df_test['g'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df_test['a'] != None, 
                                       np.logical_and(df_test['c'] == 0, 
                                                      df_test['d'] == 0)), 
                        True, False).astype(int)
df_test.head()
```

And on row 2, where I would expect to see a 0 I see a 1 while row 4 appears correct.  Test 1 (a), should be False while the second (c) and third (d) tests should be True, True.  False == True == True is False.

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   ?   2.0 1   0   0   0   0
1   None    2.0 1   0   0   0   0
2   None    2.0 0   0   0   0   1
3   None    2.0 0   1   0   0   0
4   ?   2.0 0   0   0   0   1
```

I need a way to evaluate 3 tests and return true or false as an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 3 or more conditions, use `np.logical_and.reduce` and pass a list of masks;

```
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([
        df_test['a'].notna(), df_test['c'].eq(0), df_test['d'].eq(0)])
df_test['g'] = mask.astype(int)

print(df_test)
      a    b  c  d  e  f  g
0     ?  2.0  1  0  0  0  0
1  None  2.0  1  0  0  0  0
2  None  2.0  0  0  0  0  0
3  None  2.0  0  1  0  0  0
4     ?  2.0  0  0  0  0  1
```

The subsequent `np.where` is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

<strike>df_test['htest' ] = (df_test['a'].isna() & (df_test['c'] == 0) &  (df_test['d'] == 0)).astype(int)</strike>

```
df_test['htest' ] = (df_test['a'].notna() & (df_test['c'] == 0) &  (df_test['d'] == 0)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
      a    b  c  d  e  f  htest
0     ?  2.0  1  0  0  0      0
1  None  2.0  1  0  0  0      0
2  None  2.0  0  0  0  0      0
3  None  2.0  0  1  0  0      0
4     ?  2.0  0  0  0  0      1
```

Comment: Think the first condition should be `notna`.

Comment: yes this works correctly in terms of multiple tests, changing isna() to notna() works as I would expect.